# ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host - getting this error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

> ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I am getting this error while reading a webpage in the following code:

`from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq`

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

myurl = 'https://www.amazon.in/s?k=graphics+card&ref=nb_sb_noss_2'

uClient =uReq(myurl)
```

Answer (score 0):

passing a `useragent` header seems to solve the issue.

try something like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq, Request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3"}

my_url = 'https://www.amazon.in/s?k=graphics+card&ref=nb_sb_noss_2'

uClient = uReq(Request(url=my_url, headers=headers))
```

But do know that if the data you're trying to **scrape** is dynamic, `bs4` wouldn't be of much help. consider using `pyppeteer` or `selenium`, etc.. for that.